# How to solve $\frac{y}{y'}=ln(y)$ for $y$?

Tags: calculus

$\frac{y}{y'}=\ln(y)$

$ydx=\ln(y)dy$

$dx=\frac{\ln y}{y} dy$

]$\ln(y) =z$ => $dz=dy/y$

then $x+C=z^2$

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 2):

Almost: $x+C=\int zdz=\frac12z^2$.

Comment: then $x+C$ = \{(ln(y))^2} {2}?

Comment: @LeanaK.Yes. On another note, you may want to read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

$$dx=\frac{\log y}ydy=\log y\,d(\log y)$$ so that

$$x+c=\frac12\log^2y.$$

Comment: What's y equal to then?

Comment: @LeanaK.: invert the relation, that is easy.